# Send value though Ajax on Condition?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

So my objective here is to send the data thought ajax if the password field is NOT disabled. Otherwise send the other data instead without the password data, does that make sense? I dont think the ajax is correct and if you see any improvements to the php feel free to tell me.

Code:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#editaccount', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $('input[name=accountsearch]').val($('input[name=business]').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/editaccount.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: {
            contactname: $('input[name=contactname]').val(),
            business: $('input[name=business]').val(),
            email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
            code: $('input[name=code]').val(),
            phone: $('input[name=phone]').val(),
            priceband: $('input[name=priceband]').val(),
            address: $('input[name=address]').val(),
            mon: $('input[name=mon]').val(),
            tue: $('input[name=tue]').val(),
            wed: $('input[name=wed]').val(),
            thu: $('input[name=thu]').val(),
            fri: $('input[name=fri]').val(),
            sat: $('input[name=sat]').val(),
            sund: $('input[name=sund]').val(),
            accountid: $('input[name=accountid]').val(),

            if ($('input[name=pass]').disabled = false) {
                pass: $('input[name=pass]').val()
            },
        },
        success: function(data) {
            $('#customersearch').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

How my PHP handles this:

```
if (isset($_POST['pass'])) {

    $salt = $auth->randomString();
    $newpass = $salt . $_POST['pass'];
    $newpass = $auth->hashData($newpass);

    $customer = DBPDO::getInstance()->update('customer', $accid, array(
                'businessName'      =>  $_POST['business'],
                'contactName'       =>  $_POST['contactname'],
                'email'             =>  $_POST['email'],
                'code'              =>  $_POST['code'],
                'phone'             =>  $_POST['phone'],
                'priceBand'         =>  $_POST['priceband'],
                'deliveryAddress'   =>  $_POST['address'],
                'mon'               =>  $_POST['mon'],
                'tue'               =>  $_POST['tue'],
                'wed'               =>  $_POST['wed'],
                'thu'               =>  $_POST['thu'],
                'fri'               =>  $_POST['fri'],
                'sat'               =>  $_POST['sat'],
                'sun'               =>  $_POST['sun'],
                'password'          =>  $newpass,
                'user_salt'         =>  $salt
            ));
} else {
    $customer = DBPDO::getInstance()->update('customer', $accid, array(
                'businessName'      =>  $_POST['business'],
                'contactName'       =>  $_POST['contactname'],
                'email'             =>  $_POST['email'],
                'code'              =>  $_POST['code'],
                'phone'             =>  $_POST['phone'],
                'priceBand'         =>  $_POST['priceband'],
                'deliveryAddress'   =>  $_POST['address'],
                'mon'               =>  $_POST['mon'],
                'tue'               =>  $_POST['tue'],
                'wed'               =>  $_POST['wed'],
                'thu'               =>  $_POST['thu'],
                'fri'               =>  $_POST['fri'],
                'sat'               =>  $_POST['sat'],
                'sun'               =>  $_POST['sun']
            ));
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try defining the data elsewhere first e.g.:

```
$(document).on('submit', '#editaccount', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();

    myData = {
            contactname: $('input[name=contactname]').val(),
            business: $('input[name=business]').val(),
            email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
            code: $('input[name=code]').val(),
            phone: $('input[name=phone]').val(),
            priceband: $('input[name=priceband]').val(),
            address: $('input[name=address]').val(),
            mon: $('input[name=mon]').val(),
            tue: $('input[name=tue]').val(),
            wed: $('input[name=wed]').val(),
            thu: $('input[name=thu]').val(),
            fri: $('input[name=fri]').val(),
            sat: $('input[name=sat]').val(),
            sund: $('input[name=sund]').val(),
            accountid: $('input[name=accountid]').val()
};

    if ($('input[name=pass]').disabled === false) {
            myData.pass = $('input[name=pass]').val();
    }

    $('input[name=accountsearch]').val($('input[name=business]').val());
    $.ajax({
        url: 'php/editaccount.php',
        type: "POST",
        data: myData,
        success: function(data) {
            $('#customersearch').submit();
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: I get Unexpected token on this code ? I cant seem to locate the issue though

Comment: @Elevant there were typos in the code, updated. Also you were checking for `false` with an assignment i.e. a single equals `=`

Comment: Great this seems to work, though having issues with updating new password but that is somehwere in php issue :) Thanks

Comment: Actually for some reason Pass is not arriving in PHP i think, just confirming it

Comment: do a `console.log($('input[name=pass]').disabled)` before the `if` and see what your console says.

Comment: Comes up as Undefined?

Comment: Try this `if (!$('input[name=pass]').is(':disabled')){...`

Comment: even when using if ($('input[name=pass]').disabled === false) {
            alert('Password open');
    } nothing shows up ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79125/discussion-between-rob-schmuecker-and-elevant).

Answer (score 0):

You should create object before, check if `input` is not disabled using `.prop('disabled') == false`.

```
//create object
var data = {
    contactname: $('input[name=contactname]').val(),
    ....
};

//Check if not disabled
//
if ($('input[name=pass]').prop('disabled') == false) {
    data.pass = $('input[name=pass]').val();
}

//pass dataa
$.ajax({
    data : data
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use `if` inside the `ajax`.

Create an object and then add the field according to condition.

```
$(document).on('submit', '#editaccount', function(event) {
....

var myData = {
    contactname: $('input[name=contactname]').val(),
    business: $('input[name=business]').val(),
    email: $('input[name=email]').val(),
    code: $('input[name=code]').val(),
    phone: $('input[name=phone]').val(),
    priceband: $('input[name=priceband]').val(),
    address: $('input[name=address]').val(),
    mon: $('input[name=mon]').val(),
    tue: $('input[name=tue]').val(),
    wed: $('input[name=wed]').val(),
    thu: $('input[name=thu]').val(),
    fri: $('input[name=fri]').val(),
    sat: $('input[name=sat]').val(),
    sund: $('input[name=sund]').val(),
    accountid: $('input[name=accountid]').val(),
}

if ($('input[name=pass]').prop('disabled') = false) {
    data.pass= $('input[name=pass]').val()
},

$.ajax({
    url: '...',
    data: myData
});
```

Comment: When i use this method slightly modified for PreventDefault my database does not update. what do you think might be wrong?

Comment: @Elevant Does it have something to do with `pass`?